# dblookupcombobox delhpi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Estou com um problema, coloquei essa combo, fiz o vinculo com a tabela tudo certinho ele traz a lista de cidades, enfim, ta rodado uma blz.

Queria saber se tem como colocar uma opção a mais dentro dela, que seria, tipo assim: ***TODAS***, São paulo, Campinas, Jundiaí;

Ele é passado através de paramentos, na sql. como q coloco a opção TODAS..

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia Marcelo Okada. Cara com o delphi 7 eu "acho" que não da para fazer nada DIRETO com o componente. Mas da para fazer uma GAMBIARRA com o SQL. Veja o Exemplo que te passo com a tabela cidade.

```
id_cidade int, cidade_nome varcha(50)
```

Na tabela cidade eu tenho as seguintes cidades

```
Rio de janeiro
São Paulo
Cidade A
Cidade B
```

Ai eu faria a seguinte SQL para acrecentar a palavra TODAS na TABELA CIDADE e conseguentemente aparecer no DBLukupcombobox.. Ainda Aparecendo a palavra Todas Como Primeira OPÇÃO da lista.

```
select id_cidade, cidade_nome, 1 as ordem from cidade
union all
select -1,'TODAS' , 0 as ordem

order by 3,2
```

Espero ter entendido sua necessidade e ter conseguido me expressar claramente.
Qualquer duvida sobre meu exemplo é só falar.

Comment: ola bom dia, entã qual seria o melhor programa para fazer esses softwares, qual a versão do delphi é melhor, ou existe outro?

Comment: Boa noite. Qualquer programa que você saiba usar é bom.. Se você usar um programa que você não conhece será mais difícil o desenvolvimento com ele.  Gosto muito do Delphi 7 e Tokyo. Mas também utilizo o JAVA e o PHP. Há um mundo vasto para você escolher.  O negocio é selecionar um e CAIR DE PAU em cima dele :). Tem gosto para tudo.. esse é o meu.